# How do I toggle a boolean value with a button?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a table that lists some tasks, with a column to show if they are completed or not. I have added a button to toggle the "Completed" column, but I can't seem to get the row I select to update. Can someone show me where I am going wrong?

I have created the route, button and method, and it all seems to work but the DB doesn't update (for now I just have the code to change the "completed" column to 1).

Routes:

```
Route::patch('tasks/complete/{id}', 'TaskController@updateCompleted');
Route::resource('tasks' , 'TaskController');
```

Button in view:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => array('TaskController@updateCompleted', $task->id))) }}
    {{ Form::hidden('_method', 'PATCH') }}
    {{ Form::submit('Completed?', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Controller:

```
public function updateCompleted($id)
{

    $task = Task::findOrFail($id);

    $task->completed == 1;

    $task->update();

    Session::flash('message', 'Task updated!');
    return redirect('tasks');

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `public function updateCompleted($id)...` try to return `$id` and see what is returned exactly

Comment: Returning `$id` gives me the correct id value for the row I am clicking the button on. The flash message displays, and the page redirects, but `$task->completed == 1; $task->update();` doesn't seem to do anything...

Comment: you should write `save` instead of `update`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I have tried that but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883728/save-vs-update-in-laravel

Comment: you have one more mistake: `$task->completed == 1;`. use just one equal insted of 2.  `$task->completed = 1;`

Comment: FML stupid mistake, that was the problem! Thanks!

Comment: you are always welcome

Answer (score 0):

As @rashad pointed out, you needed to use a single `=` to set the vlaue of `completed` rather than `==`.

`=` is an **assignment** operator and so is used tgo **assign** or **set** a value.

`==` is an **equality** operator and so is used to **compare** values to see if they are the same.

You then needed to call `save()` instead of `update()`.

The below is the working code:

```
public function updateCompleted($id)
{

    $task = Task::findOrFail($id);

    $task->completed = 1;

    $task->save();

    Session::flash('message', 'Task updated!');
    return redirect('tasks');

}
```