# Insert "status" data to database in AuthController

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, middleware

I want to make user only have 1 login. I already make `active` column in database with boolean data type.
And then, I use this `Auth::user()->active = true;` to insert the data to database but it seems didn't work when I try to Login. 
This is in my `AuthController`:

```
protected function authenticated(){
    if (!Auth::user()->active) {
        if(Auth::user()->role == 'Admin') {
            Auth::user()->active = true;
            return redirect('/listUser');
        } elseif (Auth::user()->role == 'CCO'){
            Auth::user()->active = true;
            return redirect('/eCalendar');
        }
        Auth::user()->active = true;
        return redirect('/eCalendars');
    } else{
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}

public function logout()
{
    Auth::user()->active = false;
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/login');
}
```

If I try to login, the `active` column in database won't change. But if logout it success to change to `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to save the data first after changing your attribute value as

```
Auth::user()->active = true;
Auth::user()->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the change by calling the method **update()**

```
protected function authenticated(){
    if (!Auth::user()->active) {
        if(Auth::user()->role == 'Admin') {
            Auth::user()->active = true;
            Auth::user()->update();
            return redirect('/listUser');
    } elseif (Auth::user()->role == 'CCO'){
        Auth::user()->active = true;
        Auth::user()->update();
        return redirect('/eCalendar');
    }
    Auth::user()->active = true;
    Auth::user()->update();
    return redirect('/eCalendars');
    } else{
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}

public function logout()
{
    Auth::user()->active = false;
    Auth::user()->update();
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/login');
}
```

Comment: it's works too, which one is better to use ? update() or save() ?

Comment: actually calling the **save()** method is performing db's **update()** method (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883728/save-vs-update-in-laravel). My opinion is that update() is more convenient.